# Neo4j - Problems with MATCH JOIN logic

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having a problem creating a JOIN (MATCH) relationship. I am using the Neo4j example for the Northwinds graph database load as my learning example.

I have 2 simple CSV files that I successfully loaded via LOAD CSV FROM HEADERS. I then set 2 indexes, one for each entity. My final step is to create the MATCH (JOIN) statement. This is where I am having problems.

After running the script, instead of telling me how many relationships it created, my return message is "(no changes, no records)". Here are my script lines:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///TestProducts.csv' AS row
CREATE (p:Product)
SET p = row
```

*Added 113 labels, created 113 nodes, set 339 properties, completed after 309 ms*.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///TestSuppliers.csv' AS row
CREATE (s:Supplier)
SET s = row
```

*Added 23 labels, created 23 nodes, set 46 properties, completed after 137 ms.*

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productID)
```

*Added 1 index, completed after 20 ms.*

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Supplier(supplierID)
```

*Added 1 index, completed after 2 ms.*

```
MATCH (p:Product),(s:Supplier)
WHERE p.supplierID = s.supplierID
CREATE (s)-[:SUPPLIES]->(p)
```

*(no changes, no records)*

Why? If I run the Northwinds example, with the example files, it works. It says 77 relationships were created. Also is there any way to see database structure? How can I debug this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be using the wrong casing for the property names. The NorthWind data uses uppercased first letters for its property names.

Try using `ProductID` and `SupplierID` in your indexes and the `MATCH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. With Neo4j there are always multiple ways to solve the problem. I did some digging and found a rather simple solution.

MATCH (a)-[r1]->()-[r3]->(b) CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:REQUIRES]-(b);

Literal Code (for me) is:
MATCH (a:Application)-[:CONSISTS_OF]->()-[:USES]->(o:Object) CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:REQUIRES]-(o);

This grouped the relationships (n2) and created a virtual relationship, making the individual n2 nodes redundant for the query.

Namaste Everyone!
Dean